# combining resources in xaml

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml, datagrid, resources

I have a window that is composed of several UserControls, three of which are DataGrids. It looks like this:

```
<DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
    <local:MainRibbon DockPanel.Dock="Top" .../>

    <local:LeaveTimeActivityGrid ... />
    <local:AdminActivityGrid ... />

    <local:TotalsFooter ... />

    <local:ProjectActivityGrid ...  />
</DockPanel>
```

I would like to combine the two middle grids into an Expander and see how that looks, but just wrapping them into an Expander is not possible since it can only have one child.

Is there an easier way to combine them other than making a new UserControl composed of them?

Cheers,
Berryl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put them inside a Grid, StackPanel, or ItemsControl.